# plotting with a logscale distribution and 0

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm trying to plot a probability distribution (say probability of k events).  It should be plotted as a logscale on the horizontal axis since the behavior at large values of k looks like k^{-alpha}.  So it's a straight line for large k on a logscale plot.

But 0 happens.

I want to plot this in a way that is easy to interpret.

For an example, consider a probability defined so that `p_0 = 0.5` and for `k= 1, 2, 3, ...` we set `p_k = Ck^{-2}` where if I've calculated correctly `C=3/pi^2`.  This should sum to 1 and produce a nice straight line for `k>0`, but obviously, I can't stick in 0.  Nevertheless it's important that the person looking at the image understand that 0 exists and has significant probability.

I'm using matplotlib (in python), but really I'm interested in how we could visualize this.  The implementation can be sorted later.

Comment: Did you look into a "symmetrical log scale", which has a linear region? `ax.xscale('symlog', linthresh=..., linscale=...)` [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.SymmetricalLogScale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to put 0 into the plot, you have apply `symlog` to x axis and `log` to y axis. I am putting some code here in case you are not familiar with matplotlib, then you can start with code below. For details, pls check [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/contents.html#).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 100
x = np.arange(0, n)
y = 3/(np.pi*np.pi)/(x[1:])**2
y = np.concatenate([[0.5], y])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
ax.plot(x, y, 'x')
ax.set_xlim(-1, n)
ax.set_xscale('symlog')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

[image]